# Is there any alternative theory that gets rid of gravitational waves, yet fits all data?

Tags: gravitational-waves

Is there any theory that gets rid of gravitational wave and still matches with all correct predictions made by standard physics theories? (e.g. General Relativity)

Comment: (Advanced) LIGO has, on 11 February 2016, announced detection of gravitational waves from a binary black hole merger with more than 5σ
certainty, so this question now seems to be asking for the impossible.

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible at long distances because of special relativity. If gravity is a long-range force, the effects must be transmitted at the speed of light, so that there must be gravitational waves. The reason is that if you shake a mass at one point, the different position of the mass must lead other masses far away to shake later, at the speed of light. The outward propagating pulse that tells the masses where the mass is is the gravitational wave.

Further, there is experimental data on binary pulsars that show the energy carried off by gravitational waves. While we don't have direct evidence that this is what is going on, the pulsar decay period is consistent with the predictions of General Relativity regarding the waves.

Comment: +1 Gravitational Waves And Propigating Fields of force are governed by specific observable laws.

Comment: Great to hear you say this Ron - if one believes in universal causality, and if one accepts STR, then you know there have to be gravitational waves even before you fire one neuron thinking about any theory of gravity - there's no other way out. People make a great deal about Einstein's theory foretelling gravitational waves but they've got things around the wrong way: the the theory had to be built to produce them from the outset, as Einstein clearly knew.

Answer (score -1):

I heard about no such theory. If space itself is a dynamic structure, which means it could change, then wave may be a necessary part of such theory

Answer (score -2):

QED theory gets rid of gravitational waves and still matches LIGO senstivity response from 35 to 250 Hz. QED here is a simple form of light-matter interaction proposed by Feynman and others. QED theory is based on Planck's law that negates the heat capacity of the atom under high EM confinement which occurs as NPs of cosmic dust in the debris of the black holes absorb heat in their surface because of their high surface-to-volume ratios. NPs stand for nanoparticles. Hence, conservation proceeds as the NPs emit light rather than increasing in temperature. See:

https://www.prlog.org/12543050-ligo-sensitivity-and-cosmic-dust.html

Similarly, all heat transfer at the nanoscale may be explained by QED theory. See:http://www.nanoqed.org, 2010-2016.